# hl7 message encoding error while parsing the message in map-reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hl7, hapi, hl7-v2

I am trying to parse a HL7 message by Hapi in map-reduce function i got *EncodingNotSupportedException* when i run the map task.
i tried to add \n or \r to the end of each segment but i am facing the same error.
the message is saved in text file and it uploaded to HDFS. should i need to add something this is my code

```
String v = value.toString();

InputStream is = new StringBufferInputStream(v);        
is = new BufferedInputStream(is);       
Hl7InputStreamMessageStringIterator iter = new Hl7InputStreamMessageStringIterator(
                    is);

    HapiContext hcontext = new DefaultHapiContext();
    Message hapiMsg;
    Parser p = hcontext.getGenericParser();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {

        String msg = iter.next();

        try {
            hapiMsg = p.parse(msg);
        } catch (EncodingNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (HL7Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
```

the sample message

```
MSH|^~\&|HIS|RIH|EKG|EKG|20150121002000||ADT^A01||P|2.5.1
EVN||20150121002000|||||CITY GENL HOSP^0133195934^NPI
PID|1||95101100001^^^^PI^CITY GENL HOSP&0133195934&NPI||SNOW^JOHN^^^MR^^L||19560121002000|M||2054-5^White^CDCREC|470 Ocean Ave^^NEW YORK^^11226^USA^C^^29051||^^^^^513^5551212|||||95101100001||||2186-5^White American^CDCREC|||1
PV1||E||E||||||||||1||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
OBX|1|NM|21612-7^PATIENT AGE REPORTED^LN||60|a^YEAR^UCUM|||||F|||201601131443
OBX|2|NM|21613-7^Urination^LN||2|a^DAY^UCUM|||||F|||19740514201500
DG1|001||4158^Diabetes^I9CDX||19740514201500|A|5478^Non-infectious
DG1|002||2222^Huntington^I9CDX||19610718121500|A|6958^Genetic
```

Comment: May be PipeParser will help you, which handles the encoding.

Comment: I used it too and i had the same error

Comment: show us, how the message  look like! Never store HL7-messages as text file, but as binary. Are you sure, that the segment delimiters are ok?

Comment: @sqlab please see the message i add it to the original post. i store 10 messages in a text file and it work perfectly but when i work on hadoop with the same messages i get the encoding error

Comment: Did you check, that your HL7 message after reading from HDFS still only contains \r as segment delimiter?

Comment: @sqlab i have text file which is contain 10 messages i edit it using 7edit and it work perfectly in normal java class. i took the first message to work on it, i stored it as it is in hdfs the error raised, i tried to add \n and \r as a segment delimiter nothing changed

Comment: Sorry, I should try to be more precise. Did you check the message in your program after reading from HDFS and before parsing, maybe by printing to the console or via the use of a debugger?

Comment: @sqlab yes i have the correct message, when i comment the code for the parsing and run the map-reduce i got all the messages i want with \n to the end of each segment, otherwise i got the error. I read smth online it say i should include the hapi libraries with the map-reduce jar, i can't do it

Comment: But is has to be a \r (x0d, "carriage return" ) as segment delimiter and not a \n (x0a "newline") as segment delimiter.

Comment: @sqlab yes when i combine the messages i use \n when it finish i make the replaceAll , idk why but this is the only way it works

Comment: I do not know why you use mapreduce and hadoop und why you need \n, but a HL7 message you want to parse must have \r as segment delimiter. There are probably some tools (maybe HL7 editors)  accepting alternative segment delimiters, but this is not standard.

Comment: @sqlab thank you i solved the problem before i read your previous comment, though, can you add an answer so me i can mark it as an answer, thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never store HL7-messages as text file, but as binary. Are you sure, that the segment delimiters are ok?

Just check your HL7 message after reading from HDFS either via printing to the console or via the use of a debugger, if the message contains only `\r` as segment delimiter before parsing.

The segment delimiter has to be a `\r`, ie x0d, "carriage return" and not a `\n`, ie x0a "newline". There are probably some tools, maybe HL7 editors,  accepting alternative segment delimiters or writing the wrong delimiter, but this is not standard.